# Eclipse STS can't select latest spring version

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

When choosing File > new Spring Project > Simple Spring Maven I cannot select the latest Spring version under 'select spring version:'.

Options are 3.0.7, 3.1.4, 3.2.3 or default.

Why am I not able to choose 4.2.2.RELEASE version ? Should I do it manually in the pom.xml everytime I start a new project ?

Thanks!

Comment: They look like maven version numbers to me.

Comment: No... It's the spring version in pom.xml

Comment: What version of STS ?  Was that version of STS released within the last 4 months ?  Eclipse Mars ?  Help -> About Eclipse -> Version: Mars Release 4.5.0 ?   "Installation Details" -> Features -> Spring IDE -> 3.7.0.20150625...... note the date of release is in the version this can help check you have recent version of things.

Comment: I never used this Eclipse Wizard before and I can confirm the dialog has these versions even in this recent June 2015 Spring IDE install.  Maybe ask at http://spring.io/questions about it.  Or look at http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ to help get started on a project.

Comment: Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Spring IDE Version: 3.7.1.201510041102-RELEASE

Both latest versions

Comment: I would recommend to use the "New Spring Starter Project" wizard to create a new Spring project based on Spring Boot and the latest Spring versions (you select the boot version in there). The other wizard is a bit outdated (as you noticed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two wizards you can use 'New Spring Project' and 'New Spring Starter Project'. Maybe the names are a little confusing. So let me explain.

The 'New Spring Project' is the 'old', 'legacy' wizard.

The 'New Spring Starter' one is the more modern wizard.

The old wizard really should have been removed when we created the new one. But as some folks using STS are really conservative and want to keep using it the wizard is still there. As its an old wizard, it uses old-style template projects which use old spring framework versions.

If you want something more modern, try the other wizard it creates an empty project using Spring Boot and up-to-date versions of spring framework.

Comment: I've created a issue ticket to make the wizards names less confusing: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4265